# How to change project type from "Cross GCC" to "Linux GCC"?

Tags: linux, eclipse

In Eclipse I've created static lib, but it seems i forgot to switch to "Linux GCC" instead of default "Cross GCC"

How to change existent project to "Linux GCC"?

Comment: Just build your software with a builder like `make`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on your project and select **Properties**. Once you're in the properties window, open C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor and you'll see a dropdown box called **Current toolchain**, where you can select which compiler configuration you'd like to use. Select **Linux GCC** and you're done!